# Eigenvalue bound for product of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

For two square matrices $A$ and $B$ that are diagonalizable and have equal dimension, let $\lambda_i(\cdot)$ be the $i^{th}$ eigenvalue and $\lambda_{\max}(\cdot)$ be the max eigenvalue.

Is it true that for all $i$, $\lambda_i(AB)\leq \lambda_i(A)\lambda_{\max}(B)$ and if so, how can one show this?

Comment: What do you mean by the $i^{\text{th}}$ eigenvalue? Are you ordering the eigenvalues?

Comment: @yugioh When you say the "$i$th eigenvalue", do you mean $\lambda_1(A) \leq \lambda_2(A) \leq \cdots$, or do you mean $\lambda_1(A) \geq \lambda_2(A) \geq \cdots$?

Comment: Consider $B=A$ and $A_{2\times2}$ has a negative and positive eigenvalue. Then all eigenvalues of $AB=A^2$ are non-negative but $\lambda_i(A)\lambda_\max(A)$ is negative atleast at one $i$. This is true regardless of whether the eigenvalues are sorted ascending or descending.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I realize the statement in the question was wrong!

Comment: If you expect people to put in the effort to answer a question, then it is polite to put in some effort yourself. For example, simply telling us where you got the problem from or explaining what you tried would be a big step forward! (For further feedback/help with asking questions, you can ask [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43593/constructive-feedback).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Look at $A=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0\\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: This isn't a valid counterexample.  The original post says $A$ and $B$ are diagonalizable.  These two non-zero nilpotent matrices of course are not diagonalizable.