# Singular values of product of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, svd

I asked this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3892519/830918) earlier and a user pointed out my error with a counterexample. However, it seems like if I change my statement slightly, all the counterexamples pointed out are not an issue anymore.

Given two diagonalizable matrices $A$ and $B$ of same dimension, is it true that

$$\sigma_i(AB) \leq \sigma_i(A)\sigma_1(B),$$

where $\sigma_i(\cdot)$ are the singular values ordered in nonincreasing order? How can one show this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this is true. One way to prove this is using the [min-max characterization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem) of singular values. In particular,
$$
\sigma_i(PQ) = \max_{S: \dim(S) = i} \min_{x \in S, \|x\| = 1} \|PQx\|\\
\leq \max_{S: \dim(S) = i} \min_{x \in S, \|x\| = 1} \|P\| \cdot \|Qx\|\\
= \sigma_1(P) \cdot \max_{S: \dim(S) = i} \min_{x \in S, \|x\| = 1} \|Qx\|
\\ = \sigma_1(P) \sigma_i(Q).
$$
With that, we have $\sigma_i(PQ) \leq \sigma_1(P) \sigma_i(Q)$. It follows that
$$
\sigma_i(AB) = \sigma_i([AB]^T) = \sigma_i(B^TA^T) \leq \sigma_1(B^T) \sigma_i(A^T) = \sigma_i(A) \sigma_1(B).
$$